# Check zip file contents in Google Drive using Apps Script not unzipping it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, zip

Do you know how to read ZIP file contents (e.g. list files in zip, compression ratio of files ...) in Google Drive by using Apps Script? Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask you about the file size of your zip file?

Comment: When you say `not unzip`, you mean you don't want to use [Utilities.unzip(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzip(BlobSource))?

Comment: @Iamblichus Yes. Want to check files in ZIP file with its compressed / uncompressed size. I wrote simple codes to do this. See my answer in below. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find Apps Script API for my purpose. I wrote simple codes to read file name and its compress ratio in zip file. (It works with file size < 50MB because of Blob.getBytes() limitation).

Referred [this document](https://docs.fileformat.com/compression/zip/) for ZIP file format.

```
const ZIP_FILE_ID = "... Add your file ID here ...";
const OFFSET_TO_COMPRESS_SIZE = 18;
const OFFSET_TO_UNCOMPRESS_SIZE = 22;
const OFFSET_TO_FILENAME_LEN = 26;
const OFFSET_TO_EXTRA_LEN = 28;
const OFFSET_TO_FILENAME = 30;

function checkEntrySignature(bytesData, start) {
  if (bytesData[start] != 0x50) return false;
  if (bytesData[start + 1] != 0x4B) return false;
  if (bytesData[start + 2] != 0x03) return false;
  if (bytesData[start + 3] != 0x04) return false;
  return true;
}

function read4bytesAsNumber(bytesData, start) {
  let numArray = Uint8Array.from(bytesData.slice(
    start, start + 4));
  var number = numArray[0];
  number += numArray[1] << 8;
  number += numArray[2] << 16;
  number += numArray[3] << 24;
  return number;
}

function read2bytesAsNumber(bytesData, start) {
  let numArray = Uint8Array.from(bytesData.slice(
    start, start + 2));
  var number = numArray[0];
  number += numArray[1] << 8;
  return number;
}

function readBytesAsString(bytesData, start, length) {
  let slicedBytes = bytesData.slice(start, start + length);
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, slicedBytes);
}

function myFunction() {
  let zipFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ZIP_FILE_ID);
  let zipBytes = zipFile.getBlob().getBytes();
  var entryIndex = 0;

  while(true) {
    isZipEntry = checkEntrySignature(zipBytes, entryIndex)
    if (isZipEntry == false) {
      break;
    }
    compressedSize = read4bytesAsNumber(zipBytes,
      entryIndex + OFFSET_TO_COMPRESS_SIZE);
    uncompressedSize = read4bytesAsNumber(zipBytes,
      entryIndex + OFFSET_TO_UNCOMPRESS_SIZE);
    compressRatio = 1 - compressedSize / uncompressedSize;
    fileNameLength = read2bytesAsNumber(zipBytes,
      entryIndex + OFFSET_TO_FILENAME_LEN);
    extraFieldLength = read2bytesAsNumber(zipBytes,
      entryIndex + OFFSET_TO_EXTRA_LEN);
    fileName = readBytesAsString(zipBytes,
      entryIndex + OFFSET_TO_FILENAME, fileNameLength);

    Logger.log(fileName + ", compressed:" + compressRatio);
    
    // calculate index to next entry
    entryIndex = entryIndex + OFFSET_TO_FILENAME + 
      compressedSize + fileNameLength + extraFieldLength;
  }
}
```

Comment: Someone knows how to overcome 50MB size limitation of Blob.getBytes()?